# Global Variable showing up as "unexpected identifier" inside body of forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some Javascript code that I am trying to refactor. The variable that is giving me problems is the `Server` variable which is a custom module I created. For some reason, when the interpreter tries to evaluate the first line of the forEach loop, the `Server` variable is coming back as an "unidentified identifier." Here is the new refactored code that is not working:

```
'use strict';

const Config = require('config');

const Server = require('./server');

let servers = [];

async function start() {
    const services = Config.get('app.services');

    try {
        services.forEach(service => {
            // An error is returned with this next line saying Server is an "unidentified identifier"
            let server = await Server.deployment(service.host, service.port);
            await server.start();
            servers.push(server);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('an error has been caught');
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    servers.forEach(server => {
        console.log(`Server running at ${server.info.uri}`);
    });
};
```

Here is the code that I had before which is working:

```
async function start() {
    try {
        // Server works as anticipated here.
        const server = await Server.deployment(Config.get('app.host'), Config.get('app.port'));
        await server.start();
        servers.push(server);

        const server2 = await Server.deployment(Config.get('app.host'), 3031);
        await server2.start();
        servers.push(server2);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('an error has been caught');
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    servers.forEach(server => {
        console.log(`Server running at ${server.info.uri}`);
    });
};
```

As you see here, I want to move my server configurations to a metadata file, then just use the forEach loop to create the server deployments that I need.

Can anybody explain why this is failing and offer any tips as to how to code this effectively?

EDIT 1: Adding exact error message for clarity.

```
let server = await Server.deployment(service.host, service.port); 
                   ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Did you `console.log(Server)` at the point it gives you the error to see what it is?  Also might want to check `console.log(services)` since that's the main thing that is different between the two blocks of code.  In the future, the EXACT error message you get with all line context would help too.

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, you basically deceived us about the actual error you were getting.  Using `await` outside of an `async` function gives you a very specific error about THAT actual issue.  Geez. Please be more diligent about accurate error reporting.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah sorry man. I just knew it wasn't a config issue. Could have definitely helped by writing the exact error message though. Will do next time for sure.
You are a bit dramatic though, and a major reason why people get put off by StackOverflow users). Here's the actual error:`let server = await Server.deployment(service.host, service.port);
                               ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` I spent 15 minutes looking over thsi before positing.

Comment: Originally, I was using VS Code to debug. But that error output I just sent you was generated by a `node index2.js` script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use `await` inside an `async` function - your `forEach` callback is not `async` at the moment, so an error is thrown when you try to use `await` inside. But simply changing the `forEach` callback to async probably won't do what you want - instead, `map` each `service` initialization to a `Promise` and call `Promise.all` on the array of promises. No need for a global `servers` variable either:

```
async function start() {
  const services = Config.get('app.services');
  try {
    const serverPromises = services.map(async (service) => {
      const server = await Server.deployment(service.host, service.port);
      await server.start();
      return server;
    });
    const servers = await Promise.all(serverPromises);
    servers.forEach(server => {
      console.log(`Server running at ${server.info.uri}`);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('an error has been caught');
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Need to start incorporating `map` more.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation of the other answer that uses a `for` loop instead of `.forEach()` so that you can iterate through your servers in sequence rather than doing them all in parallel.  Unlike `.forEach()`, a `for` loop inside an `async` function will pause for `await`.  It also makes the code a bit simpler.

```
async function start() {
  const services = Config.get('app.services');
  const servers = [];
  try {
    for (let service of services) {
      const server = await Server.deployment(service.host, service.port);
      servers.push(server);
      await server.start();
      console.log(`Server running at ${server.info.uri}`);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('an error has been caught', err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  return servers;
}
```

Either the other answer or this one will work.  I just wanted to show you how a `for` loop can be used with `await` to simplify things whereas `.forEach()` will not pause for `await`.

Comment: This would definitely work as well and is easier to work with imo. I tihnk this would be better for maintability purposes.